# Execute second function, Based on the result of First function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**data.txt**(file)

```
[{
  "ip": "171.29.39.19",
  "event": "open",
  "marketing_campaign_name": "WEBINAR : Testing Calls Radio",
  "category": ["webinar"]
}][{
  "ip": "66.249.93.80",
  "timestamp": 1509103009,
  "marketing_campaign_id": 1831733,
  "category": ["webinar"]
}]
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#demo').load('data.txt') 
    }); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/}]/gi, '},').replace(/@##|\[{/gi,'{');
    var output =res.replace(/^,\s*\/?|,\s*\/?$/g,'');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;           
    }; 
</script>
```

**requirement**

The result am getting on "onmousemove" function should be obtained without using any Functions like (alert,mouseover etc) ...  output should be at oneshot result without any operations.....

**HTML 2nd approach**

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#demo').load('data.txt')
      alert("data inserted");
    }); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/}]/gi, '},').replace(/@##|\[{/gi,'{');
    var output =res.replace(/^,\s*\/?|,\s*\/?$/g,'');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;           
    }); 
</script>
```

**requirement**

The result am getting after accepting alert at output should be obtained without using any Functions like (alert,mouseover etc) ...  output should be at oneshot result without any operations.....

(ps:i guess it need some time after first script execution,cuz the second script is relayed on first script)

Thanks a lot in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call `myFunction` after loading the text file, by passing it as a callback to `.load()` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').load('data.txt', myFunction) // Pass it here as a callback
}); 

function myFunction(theText) {
       // Here do what you want with theText
};
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: jeremy...can i send this output html data into a variable...?! cuz am wishing to make my project complete dynamic.....it would be a lot help thank you

Comment: Why yes of course, the callback function gets the whole text that you can then use like you want. Answer updated